# Any reason to fully explore Treasure Map dungeons in DQ9?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I've just reached the point in Dragon Quest IX where I can start exploring the Treasure Map dungeons, and I completed the one that the game gives you as a "starter".

It appears that the floors are (semi?) random, and can be fairly large, so I just wanted to check if there was any point in fully exploring each floor, or if I should go down as soon as I find the stairs to the next level. I did run into one blue chest, but the contents of those are never very good, so those aren't particularly exciting. Is there anything more significant to find, or is it best to just reach the boss as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the early maps, there's almost no point in fully exploring the dungeon.  Also, the floors are semi random, but set for each map.  However, you should keep track of whats the final boss in each of the early dungeons, some of the lower level bosses ones are part of quests later and is harder to find with higher level maps.

With higher level maps, there are some benefits for exploration.  Namely, looking for high end chests, and most important of all: looking for a good map for leveling, specifically Metal King Slimes.  For those, you'll want a generally wide open area with preferably none aggressive monsters coexisting with MKSs, and also not too deep into the dungeon for faster access.

One last thing, the thief skill, Treasure Eye Land, also reveals the stairs, which may help with going through the maps faster.

Answer (score 2):

Explore high level maps mainly because rare alchemy items can be found. Such as gold bars,mythril ore and orchilliam which can be sold for 25000

Answer (score 0):

Complete the grotto first time round as quickly as possible,  and if it's a high rank grotto, redo it whilst looking for chests. The reason for this is that if you complete a grotto, the whole map is revealed to you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I would just go straight to the boss because you wouldn't want to lose that much health and you would need to save some mp for the boss.

Comment: If you would like to add a comment, please use the comment box provided, rather than providing a low quality answer which is likely to be downvoted.